# Formatting a number using a computed property with .toLocaleString() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a `range` input element that's bound to an `amount` data property using `v-model`.
I have another `<p></p>` element that displays the formatted amount returned from a computed property, but the problem is, the number doesn't get formatted.

What I expect to see

```
12,000
```

What I see

```
12000
```

#### Here's a demo

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  amount: 0
  },
  computed: {
  formattedAmount(){
   return this.amount.toLocaleString()
  }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
 <h2>Range Formatter</h2>
 <p>{{formattedAmount}}</p>
 <input type="range" id="range" v-model="amount" min="0" max="1000000">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you're calling `toLocaleString` on a string, not a number, so it won't apply the formatting you're expecting. You need to add the `number` modifier to your `v-model`.

```html
v-model.number="amount"
```

By default all `<input>` elements will emit values that are strings, even in cases where you might expect a number. The `number` modifier tells Vue to convert the string to a number before updating the bound property.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    amount: 0
  },
  computed: {
    formattedAmount() {
      return this.amount.toLocaleString()
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Range Formatter</h2>
  <p>{{formattedAmount}}</p>
  <input type="range" id="range" v-model.number="amount" min="0" max="1000000">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue here is `this.amount` actually returns a string. You will need to convert it to a number first like:

```
formattedAmount() {
   return Number(this.amount).toLocaleString();
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    amount: 0
  },
  computed: {
    formattedAmount() {
      return Number(this.amount).toLocaleString()
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Range Formatter</h2>
  <p>{{formattedAmount}}</p>
  <input type="range" id="range" v-model="amount" min="0" max="1000000">
</div>
```

Or, use a [`.number`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number) modifier to change user input to be automatically typecast as a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) like:

```
<input v-model.number="amount" type="range" id="range" min="0" max="1000000">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    amount: 0
  },
  computed: {
    formattedAmount() {
      return this.amount.toLocaleString()
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Range Formatter</h2>
  <p>{{formattedAmount}}</p>
  <input type="range" id="range" v-model.number="amount" min="0" max="1000000">
</div>
```